# How do I set $PATH to factory setting in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: environment-variables

I executed this command from terminal:

```
export PATH=/home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin
```

So this is the only directory in my `$PATH`, I want to restore my path to default.

Answer (score 2):

The default PATH is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`.

If you want to add something to the path, do: `export PATH=something:$PATH` so the original PATH is retained.

Comment: now i understand, but due to what i executed i have lost my original path, please tell me way to get it back.

Comment: Your default path is in `/etc/environment`. Just do `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` and you're good to go. Alternatively, reboot.

Comment: reboot didn't do it, it still the path that i set. How can i set the default path permanently. please help me

Comment: Did you perhaps mess up `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`? What happens if you explicitly put the export command I gave above at the bottom of `~/.profile` and reboot?

Comment: when i explicitly put the export command it sets the environment for that particular terminal but in other terminal it doesn't work and same happens on reboot also.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the `~/.bashrc` file in gedit and pasted the following code at the the end of file

```
export PATH=/home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin:${PATH}
```

And it worked.

putting it before any other environment variables settings, it didn't work.